# Finding user's country on squarespace

Tags: javascript, https, geolocation, squarespace

I'd like to find the user's country on a squarespace website, which means it must be accessible with javascript only and be served on https.

I've tried using http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp and http://freegeoip.net/json/ but I believe that since they are served on http, squarespace won't accept the connection.

Comment: hhm, it looks like freegeoip is serving over https as well, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It does? Where on the site is this?

Comment: well, i simply tried the url you provided in the question with an added "https" and it works, so there shouldn't be a problem to use the service to get the location JSON.

Comment: the [`window.navigator.language`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language) method is available in all major browsers in case you need the user's preferred language and not the actual country.